# How to use collection resources and link_to with a parameter?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

Did some searching and found lots of similar questions, but nothing quite answering what I'm looking for.  Very new to Rails and have a resource:

```
resources :articles do
  collection do
    get 'search/:query' => "articles#search"
  end
end
```

I read through the Rails API on link_to and constructed this as my best guess on how to create a link to the route "search/:query" --

```
<%= link_to "Search for recipes", search_articles_path(:query => "waffles") %>
```

but that creates a link to **/articles/search?query=waffles**, not to **/articles/search/waffles** as I'd hoped.  Is there a simple way to modify this so it will work this way?  I'm also considering the possibility that this is difficult because it's not very "Railsy" and I should be looking into other ways to map this.

Edit: I'm fairly sure I could get this working by using match instead of resources, but suspect that using resources would be more idiomatic and easier to manage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Similar to Hitesh's answer:

```
resources :articles do
  get 'search/:query' => "articles#search", :on => collection, :as => :search
end
```

But to construct the link_to helper do this:

```
<%= link_to "Search for recipes", search_articles_path('waffles') %>
```

Tried this on a demo app and it worked fine. The link looked like:

```
http://localhost:3000/articles/search/waffles
```

Comment: Works great! Thank you; can't believe I didn't try adding the parameter as a string.

Comment: What does the controller look like for this example?

Answer (score 1):

```
resources :articles do
  collection do
    get 'search/:query' => "articles#search",:as=>search_articles_path
  end
end
```

use above if it is not work then use below

```
<%= link_to "Search for recipes", "/search/waffles") %>
```

Comment: I can see how the first gets me closer to where I want to be, but it doesn't resolve the parameter issue.  I think I'd prefer a matched route to your second suggestion.